# Error in changing QTableWidget in Qt

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget and I want to change the text or background color in a certain cell, but it cause an error.
I use below code:

```
MyTableWidget->item(i, j)->setText(QString::number(x));
```

or

```
MyTableWidget->item(i, j)->setBackgroundColor(colorX);
```

Thanks for your help :)

***Edit:***

For SetText, error is:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.
>
> Signal name : SIGSEGV
>
> Signal meaning : Segmentation fault

this error is occurred in setData statement (in body of setText).

And for color error is:

"The program has unexpectedly finished."

and program is crashed!

Comment: I suspect `MyTableWidget->item(i, j)` is a nullpointer. You may want to check before you dereference it.

Comment: i and j are in the valid range.

Comment: @Morteza.M Did you create and insert a `QTableWidgetItem` to the `QTableWidget` before using it?

Comment: No ... How can i do this? I add this QTableWidget by ui.

Comment: @Morteza.M Read documentation: [1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#details), [2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#details). P.S.: please write a user name with `@` symbol to answer him in comments. Otherwise SO doesn't guess that your message is for him and does not notify him.

Comment: OK @ilotXXI. Thanks.

Comment: @ilotXXI Thanks. These documents are useful. QTableWidgetItem was needed. Thanks so much.